# How to solve Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 2 supplied on Delete and Excutemany?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sqlite, sql-delete

I receive an error that `The current statement uses 1, and there are 2 supplied` when I try to `executemany()` a `DELETE` clause `WHERE` the id `PRIMARY KEY` column equals a list of key values.

#### List of key values:

`arr = ['8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13']`

#### Executemany function:

```
    def delete_emp_log_data(self,conn, cur, arr):
        try:
            query = 'DELETE FROM emp_log_tb WHERE log_id=(?)'
            cur.executemany(query,arr) #line that gives error
            conn.commit()
            return True
        except self.sql_err as err:
            print(err)
            cur.close()
            return False
```

I have tried the following:
1] Change list arr to `arr = [('8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13')]`
2] Change list arr to `arr = [['8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13']]`
3] Change list arr to tuple `arr = ('8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13')`
4] Change list arr to `arr = ['8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13',]`
5] Change query to doublequotes `query = "DELETE FROM emp_log_tb WHERE log_id=(?)"`
6] Change query to `query = 'DELETE FROM emp_log_tb WHERE log_id=?'`
7] Change query to `query = 'DELETE FROM emp_log_tb WHERE log_id=?,'` [Gives syntax error)
8] Change query to `query = 'DELETE FROM emp_log_tb WHERE log_id=,?'` [Gives syntax error)
9] Change second argument of Executemany to `cur.executemany(query,list(arr))'`
10] Change second argument of Executemany to `cur.executemany(query,arr,)'`

#### Question:

Can someone please give clue to what is wrong with my execution?

#### Motivation as to why it is not a duplicate question:

None of the other questions asked about this error used the `DELETE` clause on a `PRIMARY KEY`.

Comment: You need a list of tuples; see the answer in that question for how to turn a list of individual scalar values into that.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with which SQL clause you use, rather the number of SQL parameters and calling `executemany()` method.  For all of the various things you tried, did you search for details on `executemany()`?  Just as Shawn mentioned, the [first result from Google](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html) has its first example with data showing the format.  That doesn't mean you can't get help here, just that sometimes online docs are a better first resource than SO, especially if you don't think questions match.

Comment: @Shawn and @ C Perkins Thank you for your help.